# Content / Design / Configuration page empty

Tags: magento-2.1

I have **installed** a **theme** I bought with Magento CE 2.1.5, but the page under Content / Design / Configuration is completely blank:

[image]

I reinstalled everything several times, I tried reindexing, flushing the caches, etc., with no success.

How to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself, on the server configuration page of my admin panel the option "allow_url_fopen" was off. I turned it on, reinstalled everything, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs in source/var/log/exception.log or source/var/log/system.log
See if there is any information, a screen shot not help much to find out the error.

Comment: Here's the exception.log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/73528818012322ea099e998445bfa65e

And the system.log:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/940def7283fdffdbaa5253bddb5be94d

Thanks for the help

Comment: According to the log, it looks like the magento theme issue. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php#L672       Here is the solution for theme problem, edit that vendor file directly to the highlighted code, see if it can solve your problem.

Comment: Actually even if I install Magento 2 alone (without the theme I bought) the same problem exists, so it's not related to the theme.